# Please guide me how I can show $c=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function in
>   $\mathbb R$.Suppose $\vert f'(x)\vert\le1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$
>   then show that $\vert f(x)\vert\le1+\vert x\vert$

I've proved that $\vert f(x)\vert\le c+\vert x\vert$ for some constant $c$.

I need to show that $c=1$.

My query is it can be done...

Please give suggestions...
 Please do not answer. Only guide me

Comment: This is not true. $f(x)=x+2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: $|f(x)| \leq c + |c|$ is true for some c, but you need to know what $f$ is in order to 'fix' $c$

Comment: To complement Arctic Char's comment, we need some assumption forcing $|f(0)| \leq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. For instance take $f(x) =10$. Then $|f'(x) |\leq1$ for all $x$, but
$$
f(0)=10>1=1+|0|.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not true. For example check  the function $f(x)=x+5$.

Comment: I think you can see that $|f(x)|《|f(0)|+|x<$.

Comment: @SiriousMoradi You can use the MathJax/LaTeX symbol `\ll` for 'much less than', which renders as $\ll$ instead of a double angle bracket.